# SQL Server : display single ImageUrl with respect to id(foreign key)

Tags: sql-server

Here is the table design - table for storing Images:

[image: Table for storing Images]

I have created the table for storing the `image_url` along with the `login_id`.
My question is how to display a single `image_url` with a single `login_id` from the table.

(i.e. distinct login_id with single image_url)

Or any suggestion for resigning the table.Should I add date column in table for last image update.

Comment: Incase of mutiple Image URLs for a user, which URL do you want to display?

Comment: Url of last update image

Comment: Pls check the updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Although not secure

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE login-idf = '1170'
```

will select all data from your table for user 1170

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With due respect, you need to redesign the table. You can make `login_id` as primary key.
This ensures that the `login_id` is

1. NOT NULL, and
2. UNIQUE

This way the condition -

> (i.e. distinct login_id with single image_url)

is taken care of.

***Note -*** If you want to allow same `ImageUrl` for two or more different users, or vice-versa then create a composite primary key - `(login_id, ImageURL)`

For fetching them,

```
select login_id, ImageURL from TableName;
```

This would return all the DISTINCT pairs of login_id and ImageURL to you.

To fetch the ImageURL of **last update image**, You need to have another column for `timestamp` of insertion into the database. Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for more info on `timestamp`.

Then you could take the latest one using `max(timestamp)` (max will give the latest time).

Like (using Sub Queries)-

```
select login_id, ImageURL from TableName where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from TableName);
```

This should do.

Comment: At the same time I want single user can insert multiple images.

Comment: Yes. In that case composite primary key - `(login_id, ImageURL)` would do. In that case, which Image URL do you want for users? Any one or All Image URLs?